# C# - Unit-Tests - Random "TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired" error

Tags: c#, sql-server, tcp, entity-framework-core

We have about 13k unit/integration tests, where most of them require a `SQL Server` to work. Since already a few years now we have the problem, that we are often (daily - about 5-15 times!) randomly getting the following error:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

Every night, there are about 5-8 branches which are getting build, so 5-8 branches * 13k unit/integration tests. The affected tests are always different, so they shouldn't be the problem.

Here's our server architecture:

[image]

Every virtual machine `v-bs-qs-[1-4]` is hosting an Azure DevOps Server Agent which can run 1 pipeline at a time and 4 tests at maximum in parallel (an assembly per CPU core). Every pipeline run is using the same `SQL Server` for all 13k tests.

What we have already analyzed and checked:

- There are no entries in the `Windows Eventlog` in either one of the machines (not in `v-bs-qs-[1-4]` nor in `v-sql201Xd-ut`)
- It doesn't seem, that the errors are correlating with peaks on the host machines (CPU, Network, RAM, IO, ...).
- If a test fails with the aforementioned error, it almost always has a duration of approximately 20 seconds. Looks like a timeout - but WHERE?
- The fun thing is, that while one test is failing with a duration of 20 seconds, like 10 other tests on the same host machine and same `SQL Server` are passing? So it doesn't look like, the host machine has a connection problem to the `SQL Server`

Comment: If something requires SQL server to run it is not a unit test.

Comment: That's the reason why I always wrote `unit/integration` in combination. About 3k are real unit tests, the other are integration tests.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `CommandTimeout`? Actually does your current code set it to 20 (because the default for SqlServer is 30 secs, not 20)?

Comment: Currently, our `CommandTimeout` is the default one, so it should be 30 seconds.

Comment: Then may be turning on the [EF Core Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3) and see which command(s)/operation(s) receive the error.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thx for this tip. We are going to enable `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` and `EnableDetailedErrors` today, so tomorrow I should be able to tell, if it helped or not.

Comment: @IvanStoev Unfortunately, enabling `EF Core Logging` didn't do much. Still the same error message and `Stacktrace`.

Comment: @roli09 But at least you see the EFC/db operation that fails, right? e.g. something like *"Executing command {SQL}"*. So it is query I guess ("error has occurred when receiving results from the server"), is it specific one or just random? Also `CommandTimeout` is aggregating the time for executing SQL and reading the results, so increasing it to let say 60 sec and see if still getting the error and what time it will show (still 20 sec or something else)- after all there are really only 2 configurable timeouts in ADO.NET, connection and command.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thx again for your great input! The `Stacktrace` is always the same and it shows, that it fails on some custom `ExecutionStrategy` code from us. We use a modified version of Entity Framework Core, so maybe we just have to improve the `resiliency` and add some retry logic to better handle connection failures. Unfortunately it doesn't show the actual failing query.